# how to install phpunit on xampp via composer?

Tags: xampp, phpunit, composer-php

as implied at : ([End of Life for PEAR Installation Method](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/wiki/End-of-Life-for-PEAR-Installation-Method)) installing the phpunit via pear is not supported .so how can i install that on xampp via composer? need to uninstall prior phpunit on xampp for new one ?

Answer (score 9):

I don't think you need to use composer. I did it the fastest way for me as at the time of writing this I just installed phpunit first time and I think this is the fastest way.

1. Make sure you have xampp with PHP 7.x installed (or other version required to your version of phpunit)
2. Go to folder 
   xampp\php
   (wherever you installed your xampp)
   We will be working in this folder during entire installation. So if I say edit file etc it means in this folder.

there you should find files:

phpunit (yes there is no extension for this file)

phpunit.bat

3. Download newest version of phpunit from https://phpunit.de/
   At the time of writing this I get version phpunit 6.2 and PHP 7.1.4.
4. Copy downloaded file to xampp\php folder
   For me it's: phpunit-6.2.2.phar
   for you it might be different version.
5. Now **change** name of the **phpunit-6.2.2.phar to phpunit.phar**

I also renamed file phpunit to phpunit-org just in case.

6. Edit file phpunit.bat
7. Find line that says:

   `""%PHPBIN%" "D:\AnyFolderYouInsalledWampTo\xampp\php\phpunit" %*`

D: could be also C: and so on depends on which drive you installed Wamp. I never work on C: as in case of "format C:" I would lose my work.

7. Edit this line to look like this

   `""%PHPBIN%" "D:\AnyFolderYouInsalledWampTo\xampp\php\phpunit.phar" %*`

Yes at the end of phpunit we **add .phar**

8. Now make sure you have added your php to PATH in  Environment Variables
   To do this on Windows 10 and Windows 8

8a. In Search, search for and then select: System (Control Panel)

8b. Click the Advanced system settings link.

8c. Click Environment    Variables. In the section System Variables, find the PATH environment    variable and select it. Click Edit. If the    PATH environment       variable does not exist, click New.

8d. In the Edit System       Variable (or New System Variable) window, specify the value of the     PATH environment variable. Paste location of    your PHP. For me it      would be:     D:\AnyFolderYouInsalledWampTo\xampp\php

8e. Click OK. Close all remaining windows by clicking OK.

9. In cmd (to run cmd go to search in Windows and type cmd.exe and click Enter)
   go to drive you have xampp installed
   for me it's D:
   (I would type in cmd d:)
   then type this command

`phpunit`

you should get list of all commands available in phpunit

now type:

`phpunit --check-version`

you will get info what phpunit version you have and if you are using the newest version.

10. in case this won't work go to your \xampp\php folder in cmd and then write/paste and run this command:

    `echo @php "%~dp0phpunit.phar" %* > phpunit.cmd`

it will create phpunit.cmd file in php folder

(i would paste in cmd:

`cd AnyFolderYouInsalledWampTo\xampp\php`

for you it would be your path of xampp\php but make sure you are on drive where your xamp\php is installed
otherwise use

`cd D:\AnyFolderYouInsalledWampTo\xampp\php`

D would be letter of the disk you used for xampp\php)

Repeat step 9.

Answer (score 2):

```
composer global require phpunit/phpunit
```

This will install it in a central location, just like PEAR. But I'd suggest adding the package as a dependency of the application or package you are testing (which is supposed to use Composer for all other dependencies as well).

The reason is that test code it's still code, and it has a dependency on the correct Phpunit version, which might differ from other packages' requirements.

Call this in the main directory where composer.json of a package/application is located:

```
composer require --dev phpunit/phpunit
```

This will create an executable in "vendor/bin/phpunit", which can be used in other scripts.